# How to monitor partitions in Hive?

Tags: hive

I have two hive tables, one(Table A) of them depends on the other (Table B). I plan to automate loading of data into table A as soon as the data is available in Table B. An external process creates a new partition in Table B everyday and I plan to monitor the creation of a partition and then trigger the loading of data into table B. However, hive creates a partition as soon as a write is initiated. But, I couldn't figure out a way to monitor if the write operation on the partition has been completed. I was wondering if there is standard way of handling this situation.

There are possible workaround but which have their own cons :
1. monitor the update timestamp of the partition directory in hdfs and if the time difference between current time and the update time exceeds a certain threshold then perform the operation. 
2. Track the number of records in the partition and once it stops increasing then perform the operation.

Comment: Are you using Oozie to start this trigger?

Comment: No. The jib is triggered by a python script which executes a hive query.

Comment: Oozie is the standard way of handling these scenarios. We have a Time Stamp directory in our HDFS, which maintain data availability. We are using Oozie for our workflow management. Oozie has a concept of data availability, where one job triggers only when some condition are met [In your case timestamp for data present in Table A].